# Extract information

Tags: batch-file, find

I have long lines with information in a file. I need help to be able to search on specific information and extract only that part of the line.

The script need to work through a batch file, but I don't know if batch is the optimal language for this task.

Info.txt:

```
Time=20130101|Info=ok|Hello=1234321|Result=sunnyweather|Numbers=cow|File=hello.txt....
Time=20130532|Info=ok|Hello=78654321|Result=badweather|Numbers=horse|File=one.wav....
```

So I need to be able to extract for example the "Result=..." and export to another file.

Which scripting language would you propose and how?

Thanks on beforehand! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many lines do you have?

Hundreds:

```
If Exist Result.txt Del Result.txt
For /F "Tokens=4 Delims=^|" %%i In (Info.txt) Do Echo %%i>>Result.txt
```

Thousands or more:

Consider using SQLite shell (http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html).

Comment: Yes there are hundreds, how do i customize this script? Does Tokens=4 mean the forth section?

Comment: Yes. You may do `FOR /?` in command-line to see all FOR command options. What do you want to customize?

Comment: Okey! Is it possible to count all `|` before a word of my choice?

Answer (score 2):

you should use `sed`:

```
>echo("Time=20130101|Info=ok|Hello=1234321|Result=sunnyweather|Numbers=cow|File=hello.txt...."|sed -r "s/.*(Result=\w+).*/\1/"
Result=sunnyweather
```

[sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) for Windows.